# Keyboard shortcut for "do refactor" in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

When I rename methods and variables that appear in commented code, intellij shows those commented lines in the find panel (i.e. the lower panel) and wait for me to validate refactoring. I cannot find a way to do so without having to click on the "do refactor" button.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this action?